# How to launch terminal in a specific folder?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I've tried both launching `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal` as a process and using `std::system` to launch it from sh script (`open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal`) with different arguments (detsdir as argument, `cd destdir` etc.). Nothing works. It either opens in ~/, or it says "destdir is a directory` and logs off.

I've also tried launching it as a process with destdir set as working directory (using `QProcess::startDetached`). No luck either, it opens in ~/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, with [osascript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html):

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd ~/Desktop\""
```

This will create a new terminal window with working directory `~/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

QProcess has method setWorkingDirectory()

Comment: As I already said in my question, that was the first thing I've tried.